# Use css3drenderer to render particleSystem in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a particleSystem which contains hundreds of thousands of particles and I can render it with webglrenderer in Three.js, But it seems that mobile devices don't support webgl and I may use css3drender.

I've tried to change webglrender to css3drender and it turns out that the css3drender can't render my particleSystem, I've searched on goole and can't get any examples using css3drender to render particlesystem ,either.

What I want to know is whether I can use css3drender to render my particleSystem, thanks.